# Proxy configuration did not working with angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, http-proxy

8080 – Port where backend is hosted
4200 – my Angular2 frontend

In My Angular2 project i have file proxy.config.json with content like this

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": "true",
  "pathRewrite": {"^/api": ""}
 }
}
```

In Angular2 package.json I changed start procedure to `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config  proxy.config.json"`
When I type inside commander `npm start` then at the start I can see Proxy created: /api -> http://localhost:8080. Well, so far is good I guess.

I’m trying to send a request (Angular2)

```
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): any {
    return this.http.get("/api/getusers")
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
  }
```

I’m getting an error that http://localhost:4200/api/getusers 404 (Not Found). As we can see, nothing has been proxied. Why? Did I do something wrong?

Console output of visual studio code is

```
 10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: /api/  ->  http://localhost:8080
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
Hash: d102bcd0909a1776c844
Time: 27041ms
chunk    {0} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.map (main) 13.6 kB {2} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.map (styles) 130 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.map (vendor) 3.87 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/getusers" to "/getusers"
[HPM] GET /api/getusers ~> http://localhost:8080
```

This is browser console response:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/getusers 404 (Not Found)
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:4200/api/getusers
Subscriber.js:238 Uncaught Response {_body: "<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error re…hade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47</h3></body></html>", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}
```

Comment: have you tried with full URL http://localhost:4200/api/getusers  instead of  /api/getusers

Comment: my backend is hosted at localhost:8080/api thats why i am using proxy setting, and localhost:8080/api/getusers working fine.

Comment: what is the console output ?

Comment: I have added console output in question

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Comment: Is it working. Try removing slash while making request.```this.http.get("api/getusers")```. Your configuration is correct and I don't see any issue. Just want to debug the code, so asking.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried this way.
my proxy.conf.json file is like this:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": "true",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api": ""}
  }
}
```

and I have replaced `"start": "ng serve"` with this `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"` in package.json

my app.component.ts file is like this:

```
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): any {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/api/getusers")
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);

      })
  }
```

> in my API it provides set of user from http://localhost:8080/getusers
>   URL

Comment: But, why do you need ```http://localhost:4200/api/getUsers'```. Try providing ```this.http.get('api/getUsers')```.

Answer (score 1):

json doesn't work in my project, but in JS works.

Example: proxy.conf.js file

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
   {
    context: ['/api'],
    target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}
  }
];
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

In package.json :

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js", //this line
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
...
```

In service.ts:

`use this URL: '/api/getusers'`

Finally you shuld to start with:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}

Answer (score -1):

Use this, it's working fine.

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://172.16.2.10",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api/*": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Please expand your answer. What was the op doing wrong, why is your code working etc...