# Proxy setup in angular cli

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-cli

I have **`proxy.conf.json`**

```
{
"/api/*": {
    "target": "https://api.dev.xyz.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and I have `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` in `package.json` file. When I run my project with `npm start` it showing error

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
10% building 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  https://api.dev.xyz.com
[HPM] Proxy rewrite rule created: "^/api" ~> ""
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
```

I have checked multiple stack-overflow answers [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338804/proxy-configuration-did-not-working-with-angular-cli), but still I have been stuck here from long time.

Comment: Where do you see an error?  Except for the caniuse-lite package, there is no error. It's telling you that the rewrite rule has been applied (meaning when you make an http request like `http.get<any>('/api/something')` it will replace `/api/something` with `https://api.dev.xyz.com/something`.

Comment: Where exactly is the error?

Comment: I have API call like `https://api.dev.xyz.com/api/login` when I try to hit still it is showing `blocked by cors error in the browser console`.

Comment: How do you create the request? Is it `this.http.get('https://api.dev.xyz.com/api/login')` or `this.http.get('/api/login')` (or even `this.http.get('/api/api/login')`, given the path rewrite in your proxy file)?

Comment: I'm creating request as `this.http.get('https://api.dev.xyz.com/api/login')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After asking for more information (see the comments on the question), here's an answer:

What the proxy file is doing is creating a rewrite rule. That means whereever you create a request to `/api/something/`, it will be rewrote as `https://api.dev.xyz.com/something` and be somewhat considered as coming from the full url (hence no CORS errors).

Try requesting with `this.http.get('/api/something')` and you'll see in the console a message telling you that the request got rewritten.

Comment: If I change  request url from `https://api.dev.xyz.com/something` to `/api/something`. it is hitting http://localhost:4200/api/something instead of `https://api.dev.xyz.com/api/something`

Comment: even in the angular cli it showing   Rewriting path from `"/api/students?page=1&page_size=20&paginate=true" to "/students?page=1&page_size=20&paginate=true"`.

Comment: and `GET /api/students?page=1&page_size=20&paginate=true ~> https://api.dev.xyz.com`